# Return data from multiple tables by a single query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, User and Grade.

Table User

```
Class_ID | Name
100      | Alex
101      | Anna
```

Table Grade

```
Class_ID  | Teacher  | Subject  |  Time
  100     |   Join   |  English |  9:00
  101     |   ...    |  Math    |  10:00
```

Query all the table User, I run:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE class_ID=100;
```

Query all the table Grade, I run:

```
SELECT * FROM Grade WHERE class_ID=100;
```

How can I return

```
Name | Class_ID  | Teacher  | Subject  |  Time
Alex |  100      |   Join   |  English |  9:00
```

with just a single query?

Comment: Think `INNER JOIN`. Please add sample data and expected output to the question.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: Please add expected output also.

Comment: Ok. I updated :)

Comment: Give MySQL user guide a read in the `JOIN` section... It'll explain a lot of how to make queries using multiple tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use a simple [`Inner Join`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) between the two tables.
- It is a good practice to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) for multi table
  query.
- `User` is a [Reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U) in MySQL. So, it would be better if you can change your table name to something else. Otherwise, you may use backticks (`) around it.
- Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Try the following:

```
SELECT  u.Name, 
        u.Class_ID, 
        g.Teacher, 
        g.Subject, 
        g.Time 
FROM `User` AS u
JOIN Grade AS g 
  ON u.Class_ID = g.Class_ID 
WHERE u.Class_ID = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN query. Get an idea from this.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  u.Name, u.Class_ID, g.Teacher, g.Subject, g.Time from User u

INNER JOIN Grade g ON u.Class_ID = g.Class_ID ORDER BY u.Class_ID
```

Comment: @Alex note that `left join` is really unnecessary. Inner join is sufficient. `Left join` is inefficient when you deal with bigger tables

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Thanks for your valuable info. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN do different things, which should be the primary reason for choosing to use one over the other.

Comment: @Strawberry in this particular scenario. `left join` was unnecessary; that is why suggested that "inner join is sufficient"

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I think the statement that `left join is inefficient when you deal with bigger tables` is too simplistic an observation

Comment: @Strawberry point taken. Unfortunately cannot edit the comment now.